# Is having sex not for the purpose of making children Halal?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, children

In [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/66101/27084) one user states

> sex outside of marriage is sinful and the only reason why one should ever have sex is to have children with their spouse.

However, another user [challenges this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/66099/what-is-the-conservative-argument-against-modern-contraception/66101#comment265848_66101) saying

> This is 100% false for Judaism, and as far as I'm aware for vast majority of Christian denominations. I wouldn't be surprised if it's equally false for Islam.

So, this caused me to wonder:

**Is it Halal to have sex not for the purpose of having children?**

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the first response, yes outside of marriage it is forbidden, this is also known as zina and is a major sin. By outside of marriage this means that the man and women are not Islamically married and so this is a major sin.

“And come not near to unlawful sex. Verily, it is a Faahishah (i.e. anything that transgresses its limits: a great sin, and an evil way that leads one to hell unless Allaah Forgives him)”

[al-Isra’ 17:32]

However you can still have intercourse without the need to procreate. It is also worth mentioning that having intercourses with your spouse is seen as an act of charity.

Answering the last question in bold. Yes it is allowed to have sex without procreation.

"Of His signs is this: that He created for you spouses that you might find rest in them, and He ordained between you love and mercy." (Quran, 30:21)

Furthermore having sex with your spouse is also considered a form a charity and it is narrated

Allah's Messenger (pbuh) said: "In the sexual act of each of you there is a sadaqa." The Companions replied: "O Messenger of Allah! When one of us fulfils his sexual desire, will he be given a reward for that?" And he said, "Do you not think that were he to act upon it unlawfully, he would be sinning? Likewise, if he acts upon it lawfully he will be rewarded." - Sahih Muslim